# How to schedule n jobs on two machines so that their order of execution remains same on both machines?

Tags: combinatorics

There are n jobs that have to be scheduled. Each job requires operations on two machines. For reasons of control, the order in which the jobs are processed on the two machines is the same so what is  the number of ways in which the jobs can be scheduled ?

I am getting answer as n! 
I am getting n!, here is the explanation.
Say there are 4 jobs J1,J2,J3,J4 and two machines (as per ques) Q1 and Q2.
Now one way of scheduling is
Q1:J1 J3 J2 J4
Q2:J1 J3 J2 J4 (as order must be same for both)
So basically n jobs can be scheduled in n slots by n! ways.
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the second machine doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. You're choosing a single order for the $n$ jobs, and there are $n!$ such orders. How many machines you intend to use this order on is irrelevant.